# How can I check the items in the list on the similarities python?

Tags: python

How can I check the items in the list on the similarities in python?
I have input list, which was created:

```
a = input()
list = []
list += a
```

so if i'll have `aabbbc` the result which i'll need `2a3b1c`

Comment: what is the output of `ababbc`?

Comment: 1. Don't shadow `list`. 2. What's the point of `list = []` followed by `list += a`? 3. What effort have *you actually made*, and what's the problem with it?

Answer (score 4):

You can use `collections.Counter` to do the actual counting. Then use a generator expression with some string operations to format the result as you'd like.

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> ''.join(str(v) + k for k,v in sorted(Counter('aabbbc').items()))
'2a3b1c'
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [Counter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)

```
from collections import Counter

result = Counter('aabbbc')
print(result)
```